# Use select box value to filter data by id with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to filter a set of data from a mysql table with a select box. I create the select box with this code:

```
<select id="filter">
<option value='ALL' selected="selected">Select Student</option>
<?php
    $student_filterQ = "SELECT * FROM student";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$student_filterQ)or die('error');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        echo "<option value='";
        *echo $row['id'];*
        echo "'";
        echo "class='";
        echo $row['id'];

        echo "'>";
        echo $row['lastname'];
        echo "</option>";
}

?>

</select>
```

Notice the value of the select box is *the id of the record*. The data I want to filter is from this code:

```
<?php
    $studentQ = "SELECT * FROM student";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$studentQ)or die('error');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        echo "<div class='";
        echo $row['id'];
        echo "'></br>";
        echo "<p>";

        echo $row['firstname'];
        echo ", ";
        echo $row['lastname'];
        echo "</p>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo $row['school'];
        echo "</p>";


        echo "</div>";
}

?>
```

Notice that the id of each div is *the id of the record* which is equal to the value of the select box.

This is what I've tried:

```
$('#filter').change(function(){ // selecting a name from the select box

    var searched_student = $(this).val(); //the value of the select box  

    $(search_student).css('display','block'); //This did not work because
                                              // I need to target an id

    $(#search_student).css('display','block');//This did not work. I need quotes

    $('#search_student').css('display','block');//This did not work because the
                                    //id is not the string 'search_students'   
                                    //but the value of the variable.

    $((this).val()).css('display','block');//This did not work 
});
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Post the outputted HTML instead of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that your selector is the problem.

You need to join a string to the value of your `select` but your `div` doesn't have an `id` of the row id from mysql: it has that id as a `class`. This means that your selector should use a `.` not a `#`.

To select by class you would use something like `$(".54")`. To replace 54 with a variable, you are going to need to join a string and a variable together. Try this:

```
$('.' + searched_student)
```

Note that the `.` is a string and it is being prepended to your `searched_student` variable.

Also, watch out that you use consistent variable names: with `searched_student`, you seem to have varied it in your question.